# ANTLR4 - Help to use with gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)

Tags: c++, g++, antlr, antlr4

I am in need of help regarding using ANTLR4 with the compiler version of C ++ for gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) -> "And no, it is not possible to update.".

This is because we already have an existing application running today in this version, and we would like to integrate this application with ANTLR4 in C++.

When performing the source build in VS2013 or VS2015, and trying to integrate with our existing application it seems that it is only compatible with C++ in the above compiler version than we use today. Does this information confer? Is there any way to use ANTLR4 in our compiler version? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, current C++ runtime implementation required g++ version 5 or higher.

Details and answer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/antlr-discussion/5AJjrjQjQiw).

In your case, it's not easy to fix because C++11 required.